# Connect Monitor to PC without VGA?

Tags: display, multiple-monitors, ip

We are looking to connect a 40" (approx) monitor to one of our workstations to use as a display screen in our reception area.  The problem is the screen will be quite a distance from the workstation so running a VGA cable would be difficult (this was my first idea).

Is there a better way, there is a spare data port near the TV if we could use that in some way to resolve the issue?

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: VGA is awful over distance even with dedicated Baluns (VGA/Cat5 extenders) - depending on what you want to put on the screen you might be better off with hiding something like a raspberry pi behind the screen and just run off that.

Comment: @JamesSnell interesting, thanks. The majority of the time we just want this screen to be running a ppt presentation so it's not too difficult. The problem would be editing/running it if we went this way...

Comment: On the raspberry you can just have it display the file, and you can update that file over the network.  It would be less hassle than port replicators and all that jazz for a single screen.

Comment: Why are you limited to only VGA connections to the TV instead of DVI, DisplayPort, HDMI, Miracast.

Comment: Not asked, but a working solution is a separate small PC near the 40" screen. Something like this http://i.stack.imgur.com/3jztQ.jpg (the small PC in the picture is usually hidden in our ceiling).

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for is a [Balun](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Balun), a device that converts between balanced and unbalanced signals - this is what is needed to convert VGA to something that can pass through CAT5 without too much loss.

You can actually do it without a balun by wiring the pins directly to cat5 cable, but it won't work well for high resolution:

[image]

However, a balun is often powered in order to process the signal into something more suited to twisted pair, and then another balun at the other end to revert the signal.  A search for "VGA CAT5 balun" should get you there.

It will look something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try a port replicator. 
Read up on port replicators before purchasing one though because the one you buy might not do this.

Answer (score -1):

Do a google search for "VGA Adapters" and if supported "DVI Adapters." 
And check out shopping....
- There are so many

VGA -> RGB

VGA -> HDMI

VGA -> S-Video

VGA -> Many more, I'm sure you'll find something.

Comment: Wouldn't they all require a cable link back to the workstation though?  Is there not a way to do it the network point that's already there?  Thanks.

Comment: @Rory - You might clarify what you mean by the "network point" because I have never heard of using a networking device to handle the video/audio **(at least without converting it then converting it back).**

Comment: And that was my thinking as well, that's why I recommended the adapters